# Docker MariaDB, phpmyadmin mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin, mariadb

So I wanted to update my stack with phpmyadmin today and I cam constantly getting these errors:
**mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve**
**mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve**

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  loadbalancer:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    deploy:
      mode: global
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./cert/:/home/pi/cert/

  web-dotdotprint:
    image: obdotking/dot_php_apache:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - backend
    deploy:
      mode: global
    volumes:
      - ./code/DOTDOTPRINT:/var/www/html/
      - ./config/DOTDOTPRINT/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini
      - ./config/apache2.conf:/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
      - ./sessions_php_nfs/DOTDOTPRINT:/home/pi/sessions_php_nfs/DOTDOTPRINT/

  phpmyadmin:
    image: jackgruber/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST = mariadb
      - PMA_PORT = 8081
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname==dot1

  mariadb:
    image: linuxserver/mariadb:arm32v7-latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Cre8M8B42L
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./data:/config/databases
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname==dot5

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

*Note that this is a raspberry pi system so arm32v7 versions of dockerhub images are used.*
*phpmyadmin is not from the official image but one compiled from a 3rd party for support of arm devices*

TIA

Comment: Do the extra spaces in the `environment:` section cause trouble; does collapsing it down to `PMA_HOST=mariadb` with no spaces help?  You probably also need the port to be the standard MySQL/MariaDB port 3306, since connections between containers ignore what you set for `ports:`.

Comment: Thanks, David for your quick response. I've already tried removing the spaces and nothing. The same goes for the ports still no luck.